# How to add a $ variable to an href url

Tags: php, html

I need to add a $ variable to an href url, I have tried all I can think of as well as searching the web. I have tried concatenating but nothing I do works $id contains the id number I want to pass

```
</form>
  <input type="button"
  name="add"
  value="New Sub-group"
  onclick="location.href='prodsub.php?id={$id}'"
  style="float: right; background-color:gray; color:#fff;" />
```

Thank you

Comment: Is this PHP? Is this HTML inside an echo statement? Are there any unicorns?

Comment: What's a "$ variable"? Should this question be tagged with `php`?

Comment: added [tag:php] as I see `prodsub.php`. Revert it back if its not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If this is PHP, use:

```
onclick="location.href='prodsub.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>'"
```

Comment: Please. If this resolves your problem, mark it as the answer (the checkmark below the votes on the answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
    </form>
     <input type="button"
        name="add"
        value="New Sub-group"
        onclick="prodsub.php?id='<?php echo $id; ?>'"
       style="float: right; background-color:gray; color:#fff;" />
```